# Hibernate displaytag big lists

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, displaytag

I'm using displaytag to build tables with data from my db. This works well if the requested list isn't that big but if the list size grows over 2500 entries, fetching the result list takes very long (more than 5 min.). I was wondering if this behavior is normal.

How you handle big list / queries which return big results?

Comment: it is NOT normal. give more details of your configuration, setup, network context, etc.

Comment: I'm querying a DB2 Database with a high amount of data. Configuration are JSR-168 Portlets which using Spring 2.5.6 for my DAOs. The query is very complex and includes some excepts and IN(Selects..)

Server and Db are on the same machine

Comment: How the query performs in a SQL client?

Comment: I'm not sure it should take > 5 minutes, but displaytag doesn't like large datasets.

Comment: The query takes a while in my SQL client, but its less than 20secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/appfuse_displaytag_external_sorting_and) links to an example app of how to go about solving the problem.  Displaytag expects to be passed a full dataset to create paging links and handle sorting.  This kind of breaks the idea of paging externally on the data and fetching only those rows that are asked for (as the user pages to them).  The project linked in the article describes how to go about setting this type of thing up.

If you're working with a large database, you could also have a problem executing your query. I assume you have ruled this out.  If not, you have the SQL as mentioned earlier - I would run it through the DB2 query analyzer to see if there are any DB bottlenecks.  The next step up the chain is to run a test of the Hibernate/DAO call in a unit test without displaytag in the mix.  Again, from how you've worded things, it sounds like you've already done this.

Answer (score 0):

The Displaytag hauls and stores everything in the memory (the session). Hibernate also does that. You don't want to have the entire DB table contents at once in memory (however, if the slowdown already begins at 2500 rows, it more look like a matter of badly optimized SQL query / DB table; 2500 rows should be peanuts for a decent DB, but OK, that's another story).

Rather create a HTML table yourself with little help of [JSTL](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) [`c:forEach`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) and a shot of [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html). Keep one or two request parameters in the background in `input type="hidden"`: the first row to be displayed (`firstrow`) and eventually the amount of rows to be displayed at once (`rowcount`).

Then, in your DAO class just do a `SELECT stuff FROM data LIMIT firstrow OFFSET rowcount` or something like that depending on the DB used. In MySQL and PostgreSQL you can use the `LIMIT` and/or `OFFSET` clause like that. In Oracle you'll need to fire a subquery. In MSSQL and DB2 you'll need to create a SP. You can do that with HQL.

Then, to page through the table, just have a bunch buttons which instructs the server side code to in/decrement the `firstrow` with `rowcount` everytime. Just do the math.

**Edit**: you commented that you're using DB2. I've done a bit research and it appears that you can use the UDB OLAP function `ROW_NUMBER()` for this:

```
SELECT id, colA, colB, colC 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row, id, colA, colB, colC
        FROM
            data
        ) AS temp_data
    WHERE
        row BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

This example should return the first 10 rows from the `data` table. You can parameterize this query so that you can reuse it for every page. This is more efficient than querying the entire table in Java's memory. Also ensure that the table is properly indexed.